# What does import * in javascript stand for?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an application built with React Redux. In the code, there is a statement like this:

```
import * as test from 'util/test'
```

I'm aware of statements like this:

```
 import test from 'util/test'
```

And of statements like this:

```
 import {test} from 'util/test'
```

But `*` is new to me.

Can anyone explain to me what this syntax means and how it works?

Comment: Always read the docs! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: it is to import the whole module and refer to its named exports via property notation

Comment: Where did you see this code? It is unlikely to pass a syntax check.

Answer (score 6):

Your original question, without the `as test` part, was not valid syntax, as you can see from the [ES2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-40). Your updated example is valid, although it is not widely used for reasons which will become clear.

When you write `import * as test from 'util/test'`, you gain access to all of the exports from "util/test.js" on an object with the name `test`. Suppose, for example, that "util/test.js" exports a single constant with a value of `42`, like so:

```
// util/test.js
export const myNumber = 42;
```

Now, suppose you want to access the above constant in some other module (let's call it "index.js"). You can, of course, access it using the more typical syntax, like so:

```
// index.js
import {myNumber} from 'util/test';

console.log(myNumber); // => 42
```

Or, using the `import * as ...` syntax, you can do the following:

```
// index.js
import * as test from 'util/test';

console.log(test.myNumber); // => 42
```

In the first example, we import `myNumber` directly into the module scope; in the second example, `myNumber` is a property of `test`.

The nice thing about the `{...}` syntax is that it makes the names of our imports explicit at the top of the file. And furthermore, we get direct access to the import at the module level; we don't have to keep accessing it through some other object. That is likely why the `*` syntax is comparatively rare. But it has its uses, and you will sometimes see it, so it's good to be familiar with it nonetheless.

Comment: What happens when `'util/test'` has a default export as well as named exports? Will `import * as test from 'util/test'` give me a `test` object where `test.default` will be the default export whereas `test.myNumber` will be the `myNumber` constant exported as a named export? Thank you!